# PySpark broadcast value to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, apache-spark, pyspark

Have a PySpark broadcast value with content like this:

> [('b000jz4hqo', {'rom': 2.4051362683438153, 'clickart':
>   56.65432098765432, '950': 254.94444444444443, 'image': 3.6948470209339774, 'premier': 9.27070707070707, '000': 6.218157181571815, 'dvd': 1.287598204264871, 'broderbund': 22.169082125603865, 'pack': 2.98180636777128}), ('b0006zf55o', {'laptops': 11.588383838383837, 'desktops': 12.74722222222222,
>   'backup': 2.8015873015873014, 'win': 0.501859142607174, 'ca':
>   9.10515873015873, 'v11': 50.98888888888888, '30u': 84.98148148148148, '30pk': 254.94444444444443, 'desktop': 2.23635477582846, '1':
>   0.3231235037318687, 'arcserve': 24.28042328042328, 'computer': 0.6965695203400122, 'lap': 127.47222222222221, 'oem': 46.35353535353535, 'international': 9.44238683127572, 'associates': 7.284126984126985})]

So it is a key->list broadcast variable.

Attempts to convert broadcast.value into a dictionary results in

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Using code like

```
from itertools import izip
amazonWeightsBroadcast = sc.broadcast(amazonWeightsRDD.collect())
i = iter(amazonWeightsBroadcast.value)
amazonWeightsDict = dict(izip(i, i))
```

Also tried (gives the same "unshapable" error):

```
amazonWeightsDict = dict(amazonWeightsBroadcast.value[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(amazonWeightsBroadcast.value), 2))
```

So if it's not possible to convert a broadcast variable into a dictionary, what will be a better solution to lookup a value-list by a key?

Python 2.7.6
Spark 1.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while.. problem was in how the broadcast variable was created.
Had to use .collectAsMap() and not just .collect()
Now it is working as expected.